# How can I preserve search efficiency, and reduce RAM usage of a dictionary container?

Tags: python

I'm keeping a record of what I'm calling `profile`s.

Each `profile` is a tuple of dictionaries: `(Dict,Dict)`, and we can associate to it a unique `id`(may include characters like `_` or `-`).

I need to keep them in RAM memory for a certain time, because I'll need to search and updated some of them, and only at the end, when I no longer need the whole set of `profile`s will I flush them to persistent storage.

Currently, I'm using a dictionary/hash table to keep all of them (number of elements around 100K, but could be more), since I'll do many searches, using the `id:profile` as the `key:value` pair.

The data looks similar to this:

```
{
"Aw23_1adGF":({
     "data":
        {"contacts":[11,22],"address":"usa"},
     "meta_data":
        {"created_by":"John"}
    },{"key_3":"yes"}),
"AK23_1adGF":({
     "data":
        {"contacts":[33,44],"address":"mexico"},
     "meta_data":
        {"created_by":"Juan"}
    },{"key_3":"no"}),
# ...
}
```

Once this data structure is built, I don't need to add/delete any more elements. I only build it once, than search it many times. On certain occasions I'll need to update some element in the dictionaries that compose a profile. However, building this data object contributes to the peak RAM usage that I'm trying to diminish.

The problem is that the dictionary seems to use too much RAM.

What were my other options regarding data structures that could keep some of the search efficiency and with a small RAM footprint?

I thought of an ordered list, since the `id` seems to me to be orderable (maybe except for characters like `_` or `-`).

What data structures are there that could help me in this predicament?

Comment: Maybe edit the question to include some code that demonstrates the problem.  E.g. use the random module to create dummy data in a relevant manner.  Your description is somewhat vague to me

Comment: A dictionary is a very thin structure containing mostly pointers and hashes (i.e. different kinds of primitive numbers). If you observe significant memory usage, that's most likely your *data* taking up the memory, not the data *structure* around it.

Comment: It looks like many keys are identical strings. Did you deduplicate these?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - first comment 
The idea I have of dict in python is that it takes a considerable amount of extra space, to avoid hashing collisions, and every once in a while, will have to be resized to improve collision probabilities.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. A `dict` does, but it contains only pointers/hashes. So the extra space is on the order of pointers, not data. You'll have some factor more *pointer* space not more *data* space. A 100k item `dict` vs `list` has a size of about 5MB vs 1 MB.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi second comment  - Not sure what you mean... I redited the mock example with more 'real' data.  The id keys are different in both entries.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The data keys all are identical: `data`, `contacts`, `address`, `meta_data`, etc. If you load these naively then each of them may be a separate string object. Just having the string `"data"` 100k times takes up as much memory as the outermost `dict`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi hum... and then I could apply something like a dawg or trie for strings?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. You would deduplicate them by keeping a lookup table (`dict`) to each "canonical" instance (the lookup happens by equality but the result is by identity). There's also [`sys.intern`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sys.html#sys.intern).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @MisterMiyagi I'll read more about them.

Comment: You might be better off using a relational database to track this information.  Something like Postgres is designed for safely storing this information and allowing transactional updates to records

Comment: Maybe you should use something like redis (in memory cache)

Comment: Are you talking about server RAM or are these being passed to a client (web browser)?

Comment: How much RAM is it currently using, and how little RAM are you hoping for?